# Is there a way to execute custom JPQL query to entity's children to filter by the logged in user role in Spring Boot JPA?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I trying to execute a custom query on the entity children "Feature.items" to limit the access of the logged in user based on his role

[image: Feature entity has one to many to itself where the expected result is a tree]

[image: FeatureDto which will be transferred to the front end]

the goal is to retrieve a menu tree of the items that the logged in user has access on from the entity and to be transferred to DTO in the following form

- home
- admin

  - employee
  - department

I was able to retrieve it by executing a custom JPQL query as follow

[image: here i got the result I need just for the root element because i added in the where f.parent is null and when i remove it i got all the items on the root level]

Answer (score 0):

I was able workaround the issue by using EntityListener

in the Entity

```
@EntityListeners(FeatureListener.class)
public class Feature {
...
}
```

the entity listener

```
public class FeatureListener {
@PostLoad
private void postLoad(Feature feature) {
   ... //Here I can filter the children..
 //..every time a new instance is created

}
```